# Extjs: load data from model to label

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have to load data from model to panel's labels, but I can't see no record's values.

That's my code:

Controller fragment:

```
if (record) {
    component.down('form').loadRecord(record);
}
```

And view:

```
Ext.define('ETaxi.settings.view.InfoPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.infoPanel',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'nestedPanel'
            }]
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('ETaxi.settings.view.NestedPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.nestedPanel',

    defaultType: 'label',

    items: [{
        text: 'Title: '
    },{
        name: 'title'
    },{
        text: 'Content: '
    },{
        name: 'content'
    }]
});
```

Test model looks kinda like that:

```
Ext.define('ETaxi.settings.store.Nodes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: [
        'title',
        'content'
    ],
    data: [
        {
            title: 'test value',
            content: 'test value',
        }
    ]
});
```

This thing with `name: 'title'` works fine if I change `defaultType: 'label'` to `defaultType: 'textfield'`, but I need them to be labels.

Comment: `Ext.form.LabelView` has no property `name`, for label you use the `text` property like you do on you other elements. What are you trying to achieve? You might want to have a look at `displayfield`.

Comment: @LaurenZonneveld Yep, `displayfield` is fine. Thank you.

Comment: @LaurenZonneveld please, add it as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.form.LabelView` has no property `name`, for label you use the `text` property like you do on you other elements. What are you trying to achieve? You might want to have a look at `displayfield`.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display